# EF Core 6 Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to have a nav property and join these two entities together. In my opinion it should be a Many to many relationship since I do not have access to all the keys from EntityA to EntityB.

My intitial try to get this to work is:

Primary key of EntityA is `Guid`

```
public class EntityA {
 public Guid Guid { get; set; }
 public int CompanyId { get; set; }
 public int IndividualId { get; set; }
 public string InsuranceNumber { get; set; }
 public int InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }
 public ICollection<EntityB> EntityB { get; set; } 
}
```

Primary key of EntityB is `CompanyId, IndividualId, ParentInsuranceNumber,InsuranceCompanyId,SomeOtherProp`

```
public class EntityB {
 public int CompanyId { get; set; }
 public int IndividualId { get; set; }
 public string ParentInsuranceNumber { get; set; } // same as InsuranceNumber
 public int InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }
 public int SomeOtherProp {get; set; }
 public ICollection<EntityA> EntityA { get; set; } 
}
```

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>()
.HasMany(ac => ac.EntityB)
.WithOne()
.HasForeignKey(b => new { b.CompanyId, b.IndividualId, b.ParentInsuranceNumber, b.InsuranceCompanyId })
.HasPrincipalKey(a => new { a.CompanyId, a.IndividualId, a.InsuranceNumber, a.InsuranceCompanyId });
```

I also tried to configure it like this on both sides:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>
.HasMany(f => f.EntityB)
.WithMany(v => v.EntityA);
```

But it seems like this autocreates a join table between these two entities.

My issue with this setup is that I cannot query an `EntityA` and then add another one with the same properties into my db (but other PK of course), it seems like it tracks this entity with the autogenerated alternate key `(CompanyID, IndividualId, InsuranceNumber, InsuranceCompanyID)` which is not unique per `EntityA`, so when doing `SaveChanges` it will not be able to track the entity correctly. I know that I can query the db with `AsNoTracking` or detach the entity from the db context scope, but that is not something I would like to do in this case. I should be able to add another EntityA, since the PK is a Guid and it is unique in this case.

The EntityB should only be for "read", since these db rows already exists and will not change due to EntityA being created or updated.

Can this be done? Do I need to configure a join table and create a schema for this to work?

Comment: As per the mapping configuration, `EntityB` can't have a `ICollection<EntityA>` property. It could be a reference (not a collection) navigation (and added to the mapping). It seems to me that first you should remove the redundancies between `EntityA` and `EntityB`. If some `EntityB`'s properties are supposed to be identical to `EntityA`'s properties when the entities are connected, you should remove these properties from `EntityB`.

Comment: And that is my question, I guess that my configuration is wrong and we should assume that we can have one collection of each entity in the other. Is this doable without a join table? And also, these properties and also in both tables.

Comment: Many-to-many is implemented via join table. I don't see a third table/entity in your configuration code.

Comment: There is no join table, the reason why it is a many-to-many is because we do not have access to all the PKs from EntityB in EntityA, so we only use four of these keys and thus having a many-to-many relationship. So will this require a join table?. And also, this is only for read and not for inserting a new EntityB, these are created elsewhere.

Comment: So, you want to join two tables on properties, where the join-on columns are not unique on both sides? In this case, you are probably better off with some sort of join helper-method instead of trying to create navigation properties

Comment: @grek40 a join helper method can not be easily reusable from a Select projection though. I understand why OP wants to do as he wants todo